# Removing Excessive code

Tags: opengl, for-loop, code-cleanup

I am trying to make a game in OpenGL and want to move the camera. I had done it by using this code:

```
t.calculations(&t1, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t2, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t3, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t4, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t5, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t6, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t7, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);

t.calculations(&t8, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t9, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t10, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10 ,1);
t.calculations(&t11, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t12, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t13, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t14, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t15, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t16, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t17, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
t.calculations(&t18, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
```

But as you can see this looks like excessive repetition of code. I had tried to use the following method instead of above method:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
   t.calculations(&t+i, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
}
```

But it's not working. Can anyone tell me an alternative solution?

Comment: You have eighteen distinct variables names `t1 .. t18`? What's `t` then? Any why are the `tN` things not an array/vector?

Comment: I am not sure how to use the array in this case :/ And Not very much familiar with vectors either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the t<sub>i</sub> variables are all of the same type and the type is double:

```c
// The following sentence declares an array initialized with the 18 t variables
// think of this array as a slot container of values, the following is just syntax
// to declare and initialize the array 
// IMPORTANT: Once the array is initialized, you can't modify its structure, you can 
// replace the content of every cell, but, you can add neither remove elements from it
double t[] = { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15, t16, t17, t18 };

// Then, you can read every cell of the array using the [] operator like this:
// (Another important hint, arrays starts from '0')
for (int 0 = 1; i < 18; i++) {
   // You take the address of every ti variable stored in each "cell" of the array 
   t.calculations(&t[i], 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
}
```

Alternatevely, using a less verbose syntax (but rather complex though), the above code could be expressed like:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
   t.calculations(t + i, 5.54, 1.54, 10, 10, 1);
}
```

For more info, check the online [documentation](http://www.mycplus.com/tutorials/c-programming-tutorials/arrays/) and tutorials for arrays in c/c++. A similar syntax is widely used in another languages

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but it doesn't work. Actually  t1,t2,t3 and so on. are the variables of another class, not the type 'double'. Can you please see why this doesn't work now? Do I have to define this array in the original class?

Comment: Yes, you should do that, define the array in that class if the t<sub>i</sub> variables are members of that class, change the type accordingly (i.e., use float for the array declaration if their type is float)